# Regex for validate repeating slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regexp (javascript) to validate a string where slashes are repeated.

Must be:

/ - valid string

/abs - valid string

/abs/ - valid string

/abs/a - valid string

// - invalid string

//asd//sd/ -invalid string

/as//a - invalid string

a/a - invalid string

abs - invalid string

////////sdf///// - invalid string

I am trying this regexp:

```
(\/){1}[\w-]*
```

```
^(\/){1}[\w-]*
```

```
^(\/\w+)+(\.)?\w+(\?(\w+=[\w\d]+(&\w+=[\w\d]+)*)+){0,1}$
```

How do I write an expression to pass the validation criteria?

Comment: You don't need `regex` for such a simple task. If I understood your examples correctly, the input string is invalid if it contains two consecutive slashes. Use [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to find if the input string contains the substring `'//'`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Validation occurs with a field on the form that is not available to me. I can just set the validation parameters. In this case, a regular expression

Comment: If I could I would just do it - "////asd///sd//".replace(/\/+/g, '/')

Comment: Why are "a/a" and "abs" invalid? You need define "valid". I suggest you add a sentence such as the following after your first sentence: "A string is valid if it meets the following conditions:...". Your first sentence needs to be clarified, as you are not validating strings containing repeated forward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple regex and should work for any engine:

```
^\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*$
```

The idea is that it should always start with a forward slash and no two forward slashes should touch. You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/1BCQs3/2/

Comment: This assumes (perhaps correctly) that strings that do not begin with a forward slash are invalid. That is consistent with the examples given in the question but was not stated as a requirement of valid strings. You therefore should make that assumption explicit. Easier would be `^(?!.*\/\/)\/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice!
This works for my examples. Thank!